# Javascript files 404'ing in my Sinatra app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, sinatra

I have been developing a small app with Sinatra. Locally it works fine but when I deploy it Heroku my JavaScript paths seem to break and I have no idea what is causing this.

My directory set up is I have a "assets" folder in the root of my application with separated folders for both scripts and styles. The scripts folder has a few subdirectories. I have set my public folder in Sinatra using:

```
set :public_folder, __DIR__ + '/assets'
```

My styles work correctly and I am drawing a blank on what the problem is. Also worth noting I am using requirejs to load my JavaScript.

Here is the output from the console:

```
GET http://evening-hamlet-5644.herokuapp.com/scripts/utils/libraries/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) require.min.js:1884
GET http://evening-hamlet-5644.herokuapp.com/scripts/utils/templating/hogan.js 404 (Not Found) require.min.js:1884
2
Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.min.js:194
GET http://evening-hamlet-5644.herokuapp.com/scripts/utils/libraries/lodash.js 404 (Not Found) require.min.js:1884
Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.min.js:194
GET http://evening-hamlet-5644.herokuapp.com/scripts/utils/libraries/pusher.js 404 (Not Found) require.min.js:1884
Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Any help or a kick in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: all of those URL's 404 in a browser.... you can't access files that don't exist!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run a console with the heroku toolbelt (something like `heroku run bash --app <your app name>`) and verify if you have your JS files up.

Greetings!

Comment: Hey thanks for that thats a great tool to use and it helped me solve the issue. Basically there was a capital letter in the directory name from a previous version that was not being changed when I pushed with the correct directory name...its always something simple!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Sinatra hacker, but I don't find any **DIR** in their docs.  Try setting **DIR** to 
`File.dirname(__FILE__)`, which I do see [in their docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, I already have that assigned to DIR, so I have DIR = ::File.dirname(FILE), I probably should have put that in the original post!

Comment: I suspect there's something obviously wrong with the path.  Why don't you either create a sinatra path that returns the value of public_folder to verify?

Comment: Yeh you were exactly right, it was a capital letter in the directory name from a previous version I pushed up! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted the Sinatra code that renders the links to the javascript files (ie. haml views etc).

However, without the code, I have a feeling it may be because you should be using [Sinatra's `url` helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Generating%20URLs). If that's not it, and you post your code, I'll take another look.